# htaccess How to generate links with missing path element

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, element

Some of the generated links I have are missing a path element:

```
/channels/all//top_rated/yesterday/1&timing=time
```

while the correct path should be

```
/channels/all/All/top_rated/yesterday/1&timing=time
```

How can I insert the "**All**" part in the URL but only when it is missing?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you generate the links with _missing path element_?

Comment: Yes, how do I generate the links to include the missing path element. I'm not a programmer so finding where the code error is will be difficult especially that it is generated by Smarty.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.